# WCF service not allowing traffic via net.tcp protocol

Tags: windows, wcf, iis, wcf-binding, net.tcp

I have a WCF service hosted on IIS. It has https and net.tcp bindings enabled. The https binding works fine but net.tcp gives below error:

"The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address 'net.tcp://localhost/ServiceName.svc' is unavailable for the protocol of the address."

I tried:

- checked the bindings, both https(port 443) and net.tcp(port 808) are enabled.
- Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service and Net.Tcp Listener Adapter Service are running.
- No other service is using net.tcp port 808.
- Did a test-netconnected for port 808 and it succeeded.

I am expecting this service to not give the "Unavailable for net.tcp" error.

Comment: Could you share the configuration file ? This helps locate problems faster.

Comment: Here is the part of config file that has binding details:

Comment: If you're running Windows 10, try updating your certificates to a better version with better encryption, and set them up in IIS. Or you may see if the solution in [the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049811/restart-iisreset-disables-net-tcp-protocol) could solve the problem.